# How to deal with a query parameter in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a URL structure like so `http://localhost:3001/article?id=12345` and I want to route the article ID parameter into a React Component. My `Route` is like this `<Route path="/article?id=" component={ArticleDetail}/>`  and at the moment I am just trying to get it to print out the value of the parameter in my component like so:

```
class ArticleDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props.location;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Article Detail</h2>
                <p>This will show the full Article detail</p>
                <p>props: {location}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ArticleDetail;
```

I'm not seeing the component rendered at all though. What is the `Route` I need to get it to load the component so I can then strip out the parameter value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't match query parameters already in the `path` of your `Route`. Query parameters are just key/value pairs and could appear in random order. Matching them in the route would already make assumptions about their order.

```
<Route path="/article" component={ArticleDetail}/>
```

In `ArticleDetail` you can get the query parameter like that:

```
const id = URLSearchParams(this.props.location).search.get('id');
```

But usually you don't use query parameters anyway when dealing with ids that identify an entity. You would rather have a path like: `/article/12345` where `12345` is the article id:

```
<Route path="/article/:id" component={ArticleDetail}/>
```

Then you could access it simply like that:

```
const {id} = this.props.match.params;
```